# Using packages in Python (!pip) > Invalid character "\u21" in token

Tags: python

I am starting with Python and I have:

```
!pip install yfinance 

import yfinance as yf

data = yf.download('AAPL', start="2017-04-01", end="2019-04-30")
```

I am getting the error:

```
Invalid character "\u21" in token  >>  !pip install yfinance
```

And the warning:

```
Import "yfinance" could not be resolved Pylance   >>  import yfinance as yf
```

Why am I getting this error?

How to install packages in a project using Python?

In Angular, NET, ... there is project file with references to packages to be used.

What am I missing?

**Update**

I installed Python3 on a Mac and using VS Code with the extensions:

[image]

Comment: In what environment are you executing this code?

Comment: I am working with Visual Studio Code. I installed Python 3. I just updated my question with more information.,

Comment: That notation `!pip install...` is generally specific to Jupyter or Colab, it is not a vanilla python operation

Comment: @CoryKramer So I need to run `python3 -m pip install "SomeProject"` on the console for each package I am using on my project? Can't I define which packages I want to use and have python install them when I run the code?

Comment: That is what is thought. You cannot execute command like this in a python script. You indeed have to use pip in the terminal. You have an environment in which packages are installed, allowing you to execute the script, using your environment. But to use the package you have installed in your environment, you have to import them. When the script is interpreted, it will load the imports in memory.

Comment: Canonically you make a text file called `requirements.txt` with one dependency per line, then `python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt`. You generally do not install every time you run your code, you just install one time. There are also virtual environment [`venv`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) so you can isolate groups of dependencies per project, but they're not required if you don't want to use them.